# How to inline all JS/CSS into html with `ng build --watch=true`

Tags: angular, ng-build

I'm building webview mobile application that requires inlining JS/CSS into  single standalone `output.html` file.

My app is based on Angular and for each new build I'm running **`ng-build && html-inline`** ([ng build](https://angular.io/cli/build), [html-inline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-inline)) cli command which produces `output.html` with inlined scripts/styles - exactly what I need but it requires manual rebuild every time.

I would like to use `ng build --watch=true` so it will watch for changes - how do I achieve js/css reinlined into `output.html` on each ng build triggered?